# Archer T4U v3 Wifi problems

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom, tp-link

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I'm facing some problems with my USB Wifi dongle, Archer T4U v3.

Here is my [wireless info](https://pastebin.com/kbUar0mH).

The [official TP Link driver](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-t4u/) doesn't work, probably something to do with the kernel version?

I have both wl and 88x2bu loaded as I also have a broadcom B4360 PCIE wireless, however it has poor network speeds.

Now, both wifi adapters can be seen in settings, but Archer T4U only shows 2.4Ghz networks and not 5GHz. It is also unable to connect, constantly asking for authentication even though i've checked multiple times the password is correct. However in windows, the Archer T4U can connect to 5GHz and provide much better network speeds.

Any ideas what I might be able to do? 
Thank you